# For Enhancement MOSFET why the threshold voltage absolute value be considered?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, power-electronics

For the below question:

[image]

**Why did he take the absolute value for the threshold voltage as shown below?**

[image]

**As far as I understand we plug in the values with their signs. Am I right?**

This is from Sedra book:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which part of the text are you referring to - it isn't obvious what you mean when you say this: *Why did he take the absolute value for the threshold voltage as shown below*. It is certainly incorrect for the test to say Vth = 2 volts - that has to be an error. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Andy aka I edited and put an arrow on the confusing part.

Comment: (1) because the value gets squared, who cares! and (2) note that he is now referring to Vsg as opposed to Vgs and that reverses the sign. I don't like the way the author deals with this but that's my best guess.

Comment: @Andy aka It makes a difference. Because (2 -(-1)) = 3, however, 2 -1 = 1 and then it gets squared.

Comment: OK, yes my mistake but, the -1 volts was inside vertical lines as per this |-1V| and that means absolute value.

Comment: In other words, `|-1V|` = `+1V`

Comment: @Andy aka exactly and this what is confusing to me. Is he right in this? i.e. is 3 correct or not?

Comment: Well, 0.1 mA flows in the drain and that drops 1 volt across the 10 k resistor leaving 3 volts across the MOSFET. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Andy aka what I mean is when he have it 0.1 mA when he assumes 0.1m * (2-|-1|)^2 = 0.1 mA. The way I am used to is 0.1m * (2-(-1))^2 = 0.1m * (3)^2 = 0.9 mA.

Comment: The mathematical representation of the magnitude of \$x\$ is to enclose it in vertical lines i.e. |-\$x\$| = \$x\$. [Read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Mathematics).

Comment: consider the same equation for Nch

Comment: Author drew it upside down, so be doubtful of this sloppy author.  But it is the difference that counts.

Comment: @Andy aka see the edited question I added a note it should be like this                                                                                      vGS – Vt must always be difference
i.e. if vt is negative then we have subtract them
if vt = -1 and vgs = 1
then it should be 1-1 = 0
if vt = 1 and vgs = 1
then it should be 1-1 = 0
that is always subtract them regardless of the sign of vt being - or +

Comment: People don't like negative numbers. And to make things worse, in p-channel MOSFET we have both Vgs and VT is negative. This is why I also prefer to use positive numbers and treat the P-MOS in the same way as N-MOS.